# load html into div, menu, switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to finish javascript for load html page into div. I want load page1,page2 and so on into div id="content". If someone help me I will grateful. Thanks

[Here is jsfiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/hahatey/rh5n1emp/6/)

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
<nav>
<ul>
<li ><a  class="active" href="1.html" ><b>Page1</b></a></li>
<li ><a  href="2.html" ><b>Page2</b></a>

</li>                                        
<li ><a   href="3.html"><b>Page3</b></a>

</li>
<li ><a  href="4.html"><b>Page4</b></a></li>
<li ><a  href="5.html"><b>Page5</b></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>   
</div>

<div id="content"> </div>
```

CSS

```
nav ul ul {
display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
nav ul {
background: rgb(1, 1, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 0px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
font-family: Times New Roman;
font-size: 70%;
}
nav ul:after {
content:"";
clear: both;
display: block;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 1;
}
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a.visited {
background: rgb(177, 2, 10);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 5px 45px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
}
#menu {
position: relative;
width: 780px;
height: 35px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -388px;
overflow: hidden;
top: -20px;
}

#content {
position:       relative;
float: center;
width: 770px;
height: 670px;

clear:both;
margin:     0 auto;
border-radius: 7px;
overflow: hidden ;
top: 0px;
border: 3px solid black;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('nav ul li a').click(function(){
   $('nav ul li a').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});    



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav ul li a').click(function(e){          // when a nav link ('a' tag) is clicked...
        $('nav ul li a').removeClass('active');  // remove the css class "active" from any nav links.
        $(this).addClass('active');              // add the css class "active" to the one we clicked

        e.preventDefault(); // <-- important!    // prevent the page from navigating away
        var page = this.href;                    // get the url the link would normally go to
        $.get( page, function( data ) {          // in the background, get the content of the page for the link we have clicked
          $( "#content" ).html( data );          // load the content we have into the element with id "content"
        });
    });       
});
```

If you're saying that the page is empty when you first load it, that's expected. If you want it to load something, you'll need to manually fire off the `click` event when the page loads.. something like:

```
$('nav ul li a.active').click();                  // Get the nav link which has class "active", and fire the click() event.
```

... should do the trick.

Note -- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/rh5n1emp/7/) won't work, as it doesn't support AJAX stuff very well.
Second Note - [George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26828505/1290373) is a simpler version of this. Use that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `href` reference the file with the contents that you want to show, you can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You can get the `href` property using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Prevent the default action (redirecting to a new page) when your anchors are clicked.

You may also want to trigger the this functionality on page load for the `.active` nav button. I've added a filter and a click trigger afterwards for this reason.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $navAnchors = $('nav ul li a');
    $navAnchors.click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $navAnchors.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $('#content').load($this.prop('href'));
    }).filter('.active').click();
});
```

Notice I've assigned your matching jQuery collection to a variable, to save you making repeat selections. This way `nav ul li a` is only searched for once, on DOM load.